# Why Use Socket IO and not just Socket?

Tags: python, swift, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I've build before server-client programs (both sides where build in python by far).

Recently I started building app using swift and my goal is to add a backend to my apps using python (My app is a chat app)

I searched in the Internet a tutorials to do so, and I only saw two options to communicate between server side and mobile application, the first one is to create an API (REST) (request - response) - I can't use this solution because I want a real-time chat.
And the second option was web-sockets (socket.IO).

SO, my question is why not use the simple socket technology (like I used to use when it was only python server side to python client side -> import sockets) -  no sockets over web

Answer (score 4, accepted):

following Features You will get if you are using Socket.io or socketcluster.io (which is developed on the top of Socket IO)

- scalability :- It will scale horizontally adding more nodes (scale-out) & Linearly(scale-up)
- Reduces Payload size as message payload is compressed
- Authorisation via middle ware functions
- Reconnects Automatically if Connection drops

If You want to use your own implementation then you have to take care of the above features/Solutions to problems which arises when User-base is increases.

Comment: Socket.IO limits my complex of my algorithim, it has very defined tempate of how the backend should work (with all the disconnected, rooms and studd..), and what I want to do its little bit more complex, Is there a way of sockets in Swift that arent Socket.IO ?

Comment: You have to use it for message passing though it might have template dependency once you received the message or command depending on your use case you can route it as per your requirement in swift. Still if Socket.io is adding complexity then you can put Pub/Sub model in between your communications which will solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is Socket.IO isn't necessary anymore because all browsers worthwhile constantly keep each other in check. Socket.IO was for when browsers and servers didn't support the same technology. These days, everything is pretty much supported and Socket is perfectly safe to stick to without the use of Socket.IO. More of a breakdown here - https://codeburst.io/why-you-don-t-need-socket-io-6848f1c871cd

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way in Swift to use the simple socket ?
and I still not full understand - it is customary to make mobile app and backend speack in sockets ? (the original sockets, not socket.io and websockets)