# sockets module vs socket.io module

Tags: python, sockets, flask

I have recently learned about sockets, their differences to for example HTTP or AJAX and used it in some of my python applications for learning-purposes by setting them up via the sockets module. I now looked into using them together with flask in a web app (compared to previously only running in the console/terminal window) and noticed that nearly all examples, tutorials and documentation use socket.io . Why is that? And how does it behave differently to the sockets module?

(Note: I don´t want to use any JS in the web app, just python, as it´s what I am familiar with and I am only throwing together a proof of concept)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Use Socket IO and not just Socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50216417/why-use-socket-io-and-not-just-socket)

Comment: Are you aware that sockets operate on an entirely different level than the other things you mentioned? The question is similar to asking „why do people use cars instead of wheels?“.

Comment: Not really, as the questions I stated aren´t answered. @lepsch

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes I fundamentally know what sockets are, just don´t understand why you can´t just use the sockets library instead of the socket.io one. Or on what different levels they operate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sockets` and `socket.io` have in common that they allow two application to communicate directly over a network. However, they are very different as they operate on entirely different layers of networks.

Sockets are defined on the transport layer and allow for a very direct way of communication, avoiding the complexities (but also lacking the functionality) of higher level protocols, like http and services defined on top of http. The `sockets` library allows you to work with this type of socket.

`socket.io` defines software "sockets" for JavaScript applications, but because the library became very popular (and works quite well), implementations now exists for many languages. However, it operates on top of http (as one of the possible transports, the whole truth is a bit more complicated). The 'sockets' in `socket.io` are sockets in that they allow direct point to point communication, but they operate at a much higher level of abstraction.

As for deciding which to use - it depends on what you're looking to communicate and who or what you need to communicate it with.

To understand why something operating on the transport layer is very different from something operating on the application layer, you should perhaps read up on the OSI model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model